# PHP Rendering Age

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and I want age to update dynamically in all my posts.

I am using the below code in my functions.php:

```
function internoetics_determine_age($atts) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
'dob' => '' /* See post for date formats */
), $atts ) );
$age = floor((time() - strtotime($dob)) / 31556926);
return $age;
}
add_shortcode('age', 'internoetics_determine_age');
```

I then use the shortcode [age dob="1945"] but the result that is displayed is -16, it should be 71.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` function works with dates so `strtotime(1945)` is incorrect. `strtotime('1945-01-01')` is correct so:

```
$age = floor((time() - strtotime(((int)$dob) . '-01-01')) / 31556926);
```

But you should just use:

```
$age = date('Y') - ((int)$dob);
```

*((int)$dob) just in case $dob has different format

Comment: What if it is `[age dob="1945-01-04"]`?

Comment: `$dob = (int)$dob;`